# How filter custom posts by Advanced Custom Fields checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am creating a property site where there is a featured property on the home page. To define a property as featured I have created an acf checkbox with the value as Yes when checked. I have tried filtering the posts by checking if the checkbox is checked but I cannot figure it out. Here's my code which isn't working;

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'property',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'meta_key'          => 'featured_property',
        'meta_value'        => 'Yes'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php  
        $main_field = get_field('images');
        $first_row = $main_field[0];
        $img = $first_row['image'];
        $img_crop = $img['sizes']['fresh_size'];
    ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $img_crop; ?>" alt="featuredproperty" class="img-fluid">
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

READ THIS: for anyone attempting to do this with a checkbox like I was don't. after a little research i found out "Checkboxes are stored as serialized data and you’re not going to be able to use WP_Query to filter by a checkbox field" Use true / false instead and check if the value equals '1' or '2' depending on what you are trying to achieve.

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/using-checkbox-fields-in-custom-queries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this part:

```
'meta_key'          => 'featured_property',
'meta_value'        => 'Yes'
```

Instead, filter out who has the checkbox checked inside the loop. You are also missing parts of the loop. Try this code:

```
    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        (...)

        <!-- start of the loop -->
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
              <?php if( get_field('featured_property') ) { // << FROM HERE ?>
                  <img src="<?php echo $img_crop; ?>" alt="featuredproperty" class="img-fluid">
              <?php } // << TO HERE ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?><!-- end of the loop -->

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have cut out the first part of your code to make it easier to read.

--

Or, if you would like to use meta_key instead, try adding:

```
'compare' => 'EXISTS'
```

Comment: Thanks mate. So is it not possible to do it the way I wanted?

Comment: Since there is only one property to display I won't need the loop will I?

Comment: Try replacing meta_value with 1. That might works aswell.

Comment: As far as I can tell you still need the while-loop even though there's just one of them. It is what makes the post-object available. More precicely; $the_query->the_post() is the vital part.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I am gonna wait a little to see if someone can do it the way I originally wanted as I'd like to learn how to do that. If not I'll choose your answer. Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Turns out its not possible to query a checkbox. But your answer did work so I'll accept it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'property',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'meta_key'          => 'featured_property',
    'meta_value'        => 'Yes'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<ul>
<?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
   $images = get_field('images');
    $first_row = $main_field[0];
    $img = $first_row['image'];
    $img_crop = $img['sizes']['fresh_size'];
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $img_crop; ?>" alt="featuredproperty" class="img-fluid">
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). 
?>
```

Please check your settings under acf checkbox "Choices", check if it "Yes : Yes" or "yes : Yes" and fix your 'meta_value' if you have "yes : Yes" to 'meta_value' => 'yes'. Checkbox saves data as value-label. I think you have issue with your configuration of checkbox.

What type of 'images' field do you use? Is it repeater or gallery? If you using gallery then for src of the image you need to use:
    $images = get_field('images');
    $img_crop = $images[0]['sizes']['fresh_size'];

Comment: For the image field I am using a repeater. But in this case I just want the first image inside the repeater. I'll add an image of my "Choises" so you can see. Just give me a sec. Thanks

Comment: I've added the image to my post

Comment: You have wrong value in "Choices" replace it with "Yes : Yes" with spaces, save and try again. Check if "Choices" have exactly "Yes : Yes" value.

Comment: It won't allow me to change Yes to Yes : Yes, every time I update it reverts back to Yes

Comment: ok, can you add a new line in Choises with "No", and check if it changes?

Comment: It allows me to add "No" but not "Yes : Yes"

Comment: ok, try to replace 'meta_value' => 'Yes' with 'meta_value' => 'yes'.

Comment: do you think a different field type would help?

Comment: It allows me to save. "yes : Yes" but it still doesn't work

Comment: you can try True / False acf field. But your current field must work too, the issue is in values.

Comment: when I print_r($query); I can see Array ( [key] => featured_property [value] => Yes so I don't get why this doesn't work

Comment: if it allows you to save "yes : Yes" then replace 'meta_value' => 'Yes' with 'meta_value' => 'yes'